# How to use structs declared in the header and defined in source code by a function

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I am trying to store the main features of my hardware configuration in one place, so I created structures for it. I declared them as `typedef` in a header file, and I want to create and define the actual structures in a function, that I can call when the application starts. (I am using an STM32F04 board with chibiOS running on it.)

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef HW_INIT_INCLUDED
#define HW_INIT_INCLUDED

#include <mcuconf.h>
#include <hal.h>
#include <ch.h>

struct Recievers;
struct LEDs;
struct Ultrasonic;

typedef struct Recievers{
    int iD;
    int port;
    int pinNumber;
} Reciever;

typedef struct LEDs{
    int iD;
    char port;
    int pinNumber;
    bool status;
    float dutyCycleConstant;
} LED;

typedef struct Ultrasonic{
    char port;
    int pinNumber;
}Ultrasonic;


/*
Initaliases the values of hw parameters.
*/

void hardWareInit(struct Recievers Reciever, struct LEDs LED, struct Ultrasonic Ultrasonic);

#endif // HW_INIT_INCLUDED
```

and here is the source code:

```
#include <hw_init.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void hardWareInit(struct Recievers Reciever, struct LEDs LED, struct    Ultrasonic Ultrasonic)
{
    Reciever Reciever1, Reciever2, Reciever3, Reciever4;
    LED LED1, LED2, LED3;
    Ultrasonic Ultrasonic1;

    Reciever1.iD = 1;
    Reciever1.port = GPIOF;
    Reciever1.pinNumber = 1;

    Reciever2.iD = 2;
    Reciever2.port = GPIOG;
    Reciever2.pinNumber = 1;

    Reciever3.iD = 3;
    Reciever3.port = GPIOI;
    Reciever3.pinNumber = 1;

    Reciever4.iD = 3;
    Reciever4.port = GPIOE;
    Reciever4.pinNumber = 1;

    LED1.iD = 1;
    LED1.port = GPIOD;
    LED1.pinNumber = 16;
    LED1.status = 0;
    LED1.dutyCycleConstant = 0.3;

    LED2.iD = 2;
    LED1.port = GPIOD;
    LED2.pinNumber = 16;
    LED2.status = 0;
    LED2.dutyCycleConstant = 0.3;

    LED3.iD = 3;
    LED1.port = GPIOD;
    LED3.pinNumber = 16;
    LED3.status = 0;
    LED3.dutyCycleConstant = 0.3;

    Ultrasonic1.port = GPIOC;
    Ultrasonic1.pinNumber = 1;
}
```

When I try to compile, it basically gives these errors for every struct I try to create:

hw_init.c:8:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
     Reciever Reciever1;
     ^
hw_init.c:8:14: error: expected ';' before 'Reciever1'
     Reciever Reciever1;

Comment: You are aware that you name a formal parameter of your function like the typedef (`Reciever`)? I assume that it overrides the typedef which completely invalidates your declarations in the function.

Comment: What are those parameters to your function? For example `struct Recievers Reciever` is saying the caller needs to pass in a `struct Reciever` (note that's not how you spell "receiver"!), but you never use it, and the fact that the parameter is called `Reciever` means the function can't see the `typedef`, also called `Reciever`, from the header file - this is what's causing your errors.

Comment: Also, defining (and filling) local structure objects in your function won't get you very far; the objects will disappear once the function is finished. Perhaps you want to fill global objects?

Comment: It will not solve your problem, but I am sure that there is a mistake in the code. I guess you want set the port of EACH LED, but you are always set LED1.port = GPIO. Seems like you forgot to change the number, dont you?

Comment: Don't give variables names using the same case convention as objects. Pick a scheme for each and stick to it. I also don't know why C programmers typedef structs so often as it just provides further opportunities for confusion like this. (What am I missing?)

Comment: You got the same name twice in your struct: typedef struct "Ultrasonic"{
    char port;
    int pinNumber;
}"Ultrasonic";

Comment: First of all, thank you for all your answers, they solved the issue. I mistyped receiver, and i just copied it all the way. And as for xy36, that is just the bonus that you noticed I used LED1.port for all the structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to compile, it basically gives these errors for every struct I try to create:
>
> hw_init.c:8:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value] Reciever  Reciever1;
> hw_init.c:8:14: error: expected ';' before 'Reciever1' Reciever Reciever1;

You get the error message because you use the word `Reciever` for a typedef'd struct as well as the first function parameter:

```
void hardWareInit(struct Recievers Reciever, struct LEDs LED, struct    Ultrasonic Ultrasonic)
```

You should use a diffent designator for the first parameter.

Further I suggest to name `reciever` to  `receiver`.